# How to get the External/Public IP Address in android?

Tags: java, android, ip, external, public

I Couldn't get any IP when I run the following method:

```
System.out.println("IP: " +getIpAddress());
public String getIpAddress() 
 {
   String ip = null;
   try 
   {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      //HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://ip2country.sourceforge.net/ip2c.php?format=JSON");
      HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://agentgatech.appspot.com/");

      HttpResponse response;
      System.out.println("IP: 1");
      response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
      System.out.println("IP: 2" +response.getStatusLine().toString());

      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      entity.getContentLength();
      String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
      System.out.println("IP 3" +getApplicationContext() +str);
      JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(str);
      ip = json_data.getString("ip");
      System.out.println("IP 4" +getApplicationContext() +ip);
   }
       catch (Exception e)
      {

      }

   return ip;
 }
```

I have already added thw following to the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

I just got the following printed out!:

```
    IP: 1
    IP: null
```

Can any one tell me why? where is the wrong in this code?

Edit:
Just for the others, the answer is by using thread as shown bellow:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       // HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://ip2country.sourceforge.net/ip2c.php?format=JSON");
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://agentgatech.appspot.com/");

        HttpResponse response;
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        entity.getContentLength();
        String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        System.out.println("External IP: " +str);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
   });
```

To start it:

```
thread.start();
```

Comment: Please log the exception rather than ignoring it.

Comment: I didn't get any exception! or stopping the app!

Comment: That is because you are not logging the exception, but instead are ignoring it in your `catch` block. Clearly, you are getting an exception, otherwise your other IP lines would be showing in LogCat.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your useful comment, I added the exception catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();} and I got this error which cause stopping the app: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testttt/com.example.testttt.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Ip address is already here: `String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);`

Comment: Ok thanks for every one, I solved the proble by put the code inside thread it is work now:  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //Your code goes here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

thread.start();